# SHELL : awk trim/replace

Tags: shell, awk

I need some help. 
I have this **info.txt**

```
  [hello] world
  { gg
    }
```

**how can I output to this, the only string remain is within the bracket**

```
   hello
```

my current command is this

```
  awk '{ gsub("[]].*",""); print $0 }' info.txt
```

the output is

```
  [hello
  { gg
    }
```

Comment: What is the rule here? Extract the first occurrence of text inside square brackets? Try `grep -o '\[[^][]*]' info.txt | head -1 | sed 's/[][]//g'`

Comment: my aim on this is the only string that remain is inside the bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk` could you please try.

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/.*\[|\].*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -v RS="" 'match($0,/\[.*\]/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file
```

OR with simple `awk`:

```
awk -F"[][]" '/\[.*\]/{print $2}' Input_file


awk -F"[][]" '   ##Starting awk program here and setting field separator as [ and ] here.
/\[.*\]/{        ##Checking line if it has [.*] in it then do following.
  print $2       ##Print 2nd field of that line.
}
' Input_file     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: thanks sir. this is working. can you give a details for the syntax/commands use?

Comment: Will add it in a min or so

Comment: hi sir. can i ask some help.
with this info. the command does not work

 [hello] world
  { gg[test]
    }
i only want hello to be the output

Comment: @rkevx21, when I run `awk -F"[][]" '/\[.*\]/{print $2}' Input_file` with your posted input in comments I get `hello` in output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197652/discussion-between-rkevx21-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep and this good [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13472) :

> For instance, if you wanted to match the word between foo and bar, you
> could use:
>
> ```
> grep -oP 'foo \K\w+(?= bar)' test.txt
> ```

You could use :

```
grep -oP "\[\K\w+(?=\])" info.txt
```